# Ruby on rails image gallery using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, gallery

I'm creating an image gallery website, and have some problems. I tried searching, but it's hard because i cannot really describe this problem.

i want to have thumbnail images on my index page, but i can't get it working.

why does this code inside /views/index.html.erb

```
    <% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
    <%= image_tag gallery.photos(:small).last %>
    <%= link_to gallery.title, gallery_path(gallery) %>
```

doesn't show me photos, just blank spaces where photos supposed to appear. When i right click on them to open in new tab, it links to /images/#..... and gives No routes error.

On show.html.erb pictures are shown with this code:

```
      <% @gallery.photos.each do |photo|%>
      <%= image_tag photo.image(:medium) %>
     <% end %>
```

models are: gallery has many photos, photos belongs to gallery.

gallery controller:
        def index
           @galleries = Gallery.all.order(created_at: :desc)
        end

```
    def show
        @gallery = Gallery.find(params[:id])
    end
```

routes: 
        resources :galleries
        resources :photos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@rubynuby: Just try this:

```
<% @galleries.each do |gallery| %>
<%= image_tag gallery.photos.last.image.url(:small) %>
<%= link_to gallery.title, gallery_path(gallery) %>
```

As what I observed form you question is:

in models/gallery.rb

```
class Gallery
  has_many :photos
end
```

in models/photo.rb

```
class Photo
  belongs_to :gallery
  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
                      small:  '150x150>',
                      medium: '600X600>'
                    }

end
```

So as per your requirement, you need call `image` on photo, i.e. `photo.image.url(<style>)`